# How to unit test the controller action that has membership.getuser in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, unit-testing

I am very new to ASP.NET MVC. Could you please advise how do I unit Membership.GetUser from below code ? I have searched through different forums but didn't get the answer I am looking for. I may be doing something wrong.

```
private readonly IMyRepository _respository;
public class MyController
{
    public MyController() : this(new MyRepository())
    {

    }
    public MyController(IMyRepository myrepository)
    {
        _respository = myrepository;            
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var todoList = _repository.GetAllTodoItems();
        if (todoList.Count() == 0)
            return Content("No Todo List Items found");
        else
        {                
            return View("List", todoList);
        }
    }
}
public class MyRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<CustomModel> GetAllTodoItems()
    {
        var userid = (int)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
        var todoList = _dbcontext.CustomList.Where(e => e.UserId == userid);

        return todoList;
    }
}
```

Could someone please provide a detailed response ?

Comment: Can someone please reply to my question ??

Comment: By the way, why do you need default constructor for controller?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call static methods like DateTime.Now() you make your code untestable. ...unless you use some isolation framework like Typemock which unmercifully changes runtime behavior for the executed test.

Create some interface and its implementation wih methods making static calls to Membership.

Inject this interface as dependency in your controller.

Then in your Unit Tests you'll be able to mock this interface and check calls or return values you need for thetest.

Comment: I did the modifications as you mentioned. But, I am getting below error when I run the unit test that calls "return (int)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey"                                                                                        Access to the path 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\App_Data' is denied. Can you please help me ?

Comment: Inside your test code do you call the implementation that calls Membership?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are using it right because your repository depends on `Membership.GetUser()`. It is security feature but repository should be responsible only for getting the data.

It will be better if you move calls `Membership.GetUser()` one level up to `MyController` and update repository API to

```
public IEnumerable<CustomModel> GetAllTodoItems(int userId)
```

It will help you to write separate unit-test on Repository.

As a second step to be able to write test on `MyController` you can move `Membership.GetUser()` dependency to separate service (like SecurityService) and inject it to `MyController` as an interface. In unit test you will initialize `MyController` with fake or mock of SecurityService.

Comment: Thanks for the response Alexander. I have created the interface and moved out the Membership.GetUser logic. But, I was unable to execute the test. Below is the test FYI. Can you please help ?                                                             [TestMethod]public void TestMethod1() { var service = new Mock<ISecurityService>(); service.Setup(c => c.GetUser()).Returns(1); var controller = new MyController(); var p = controller.Index() as ViewResult;}                      I have injected the ISecurityService in the repository constructor but I am getting "Access Denied" error.

Comment: @ramsudheer Controller should use ISecurityService, and in your tcode I do not see where you inject mocked instance inside controller.

Comment: @ramsudheer Oh... Now I noticed Membership is used inside repository. Then you should bother to test repository separately. And mock repo when testing controller.

Comment: Thanks voroninp. MyController default constructor will call MyController(IRepository, ISecurityservice). I am getting currently loggedin user by using Membership.Getuser() which is placed inside securityserviceImpl class. So, when I call var p = controller.Index as ViewResult; I am getting the Access denied error. FYI - inside the Index action I am getting the currently logged-in userId from securityserviceImpl.GetUser(). Am I doing something wrong ? Can you please advise ?